# clearInterval() doesn't clear interval in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to increment the number of users after each 200ms till 5000 with the below code. But it doesn't clear the interval when the number of users greater than 5000.

```
const Cards = () => {
const [users, setUsers] = useState(40);

useEffect(() => {
    const setIntervalUsers = setInterval(() => {
        setUsers((prevUsers) => prevUsers = prevUsers + 100)
    }, 200);

    if (users >= 5000) {
        console.log('ok');
        clearInterval(setIntervalUsers)
    }
}, []);


return (<div>number of users {users} </div>)}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you return a clean-up function so you don't register the interval multiple times between re-renders/mounts.

Also, use a `ref` set with `useRef` and a separate `useEffect` that would watch changes in `users` and clear the interval there.

As an example, like so:

```js
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
const Cards = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(40);
  const intervalRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (users >= 5000) {
      console.log("ok");
      clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    }
  }, [users]);

  useEffect(() => {
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setUsers((prevUsers) => (prevUsers = prevUsers + 100));
    }, 200);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
  }, []);

  return <div>number of users {users} </div>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The way how you check for your condition `users >= 5000` is not working because `users` is not listed as a dependency in your `useEffect` hook. Therefore the hook only runs once but doesnt run again when `users` change. Because of that you only check for `40 >= 5000` once at the beginning.

An easier way to handle that is without a `setInterval` way.

```
export const Cards = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(40);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // your break condition
    if (users >= 5000) return;
    
    const increment = async () => {
      // your interval
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 200));
      setUsers((prevState) => prevState + 100);
    }
    
    // call your callback
    increment();
    
    // make the function run when users change.
  }, [users]);
  
  return <p>current number of users {users}</p>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesnt work because:

- you never call the useEffect again to check if the condition is met
- the interval ref is lost

I made a working sample of your code here : https://codepen.io/aSH-uncover/pen/wvmYdNy

Addintionnaly you should clean the interval when the component is destroyed by returning the cleanInterval call in the hook that created the inteerval

```
const Card = ({ step }) => {
  const intervals = useRef({})
  
  const [users, setUsers] = useState(40)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    intervals.users = setInterval(() => {
      setUsers((prevUsers) => prevUsers = prevUsers + step)
    }, 200)
    return () => clearInterval(intervals.users)
  }, [])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (users >= 5000) {
        clearInterval(intervals.users)
    }
  }, [users])
  
  return (<div>number of users {users} </div>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this. You can try it out. Although there are many ways suggested above

```
 const [users, setUsers] = useState(40);
 const [max_user, setMaxUser] = useState(true);

  let setIntervalUsers: any;
  let sprevUsers = 0;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (max_user) {
      setIntervalUsers = setInterval(() => {
        sprevUsers += 100;
        if (sprevUsers >= 5000) {
          setMaxUser(false);
          clearInterval(setIntervalUsers);
        } else {
          setUsers(sprevUsers);
        }
      }, 200);
    }
  }, []);
```